# How to count the number of times a certain value occurs in a column postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table with two columns. The first is called 'animal' and lists different types of animals such as cat, dog, bird etc. The second column 'num' lists different numbers.

I want to count how many times the word 'cat' appears in the 'animal' column so that I be able to output 'cat' and then it's frequency.

```
SELECT animal, count(*) as Total FROM mydata GROUP BY animal;
```

However, this is outputting all animals and their frequencies, but I would just like to to limit my output to cat and its frequency only.

When I try to do:

```
SELECT count(animal) FROM mydata WHERE animal = 'cat';
```

I am given an output that says the total is 0.

Comment: `where animal = 'cat'`?

Comment: Should I delete the "group by" condition?

Answer (score 0):

This should satisfy your requirements.

```
SELECT 'cat' as animal, count(*) as Total FROM mydata where animal = 'cat';
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I am unfortunately getting that the total is 0

Comment: Does anything get returned with `select * from mydata where animal = 'cat';`?

Comment: No, I get a table without any values

Comment: @Angie Then the reason you get zero is that that is the correct answer.  You don't have any 'cat's.